# Object Detection Using YOLOv3

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-c++, yolo

I was implementing YOLOv3 for object detection using python in visual studio. My code is working fine but it's not detecting bounding boxes with it's label which means that bounding boxes code is not working. I am unable to find the error behind it. I have used yolov3 pretrained models in my code. Can any one tell me what are the possible reasons?

```
The link for the code is : 
<https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/ObjectDetection-YOLO/object_detection_yolo.py>
# Get the names of the output layers
def getOutputsNames(net):
    # Get the names of all the layers in the network
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    # Get the names of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


def drawPred(classId, conf, left, top, right, bottom):
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 178, 50), 3)

    label = '%.2f' % conf

    # Get the label for the class name and its confidence
    if classes:
        assert(classId < len(classes))
        label = '%s:%s' % (classes[classId], label)

    #Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    labelSize, baseLine = cv.getTextSize(label, cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
    top = max(top, labelSize[1])
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top - round(1.5*labelSize[1])), (left + round(1.5*labelSize[0]), top + baseLine), (255, 255, 255), cv.FILLED)
    cv.putText(frame, label, (left, top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0,0,0), 1)

# Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence using non-maxima suppression
def postprocess(frame, outs):
    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

try to replace `layer_names[i[0] - 1]` with `layer_name[i-1]`

```
def getOutputsNames(net):
    # Get the names of all the layers in the network
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    # Get the names of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
    return [layersNames[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```